# Plotting fitted values for an nlme model

Tags: r, data-visualization, mixed-model

I just got the output of my `lme` (`nlme`) model called `shalit5` with syntax:

```
biomass ~ fyear + protection, random = 1|coast/site
```

Both `fyear` and `protection` are significant, but I am having trouble plotting the fitted values to visualise the differences between the 2 levels of `protection`.

I am trying to use an adjustment of the code below, since I had no trouble using it to sketch the fitted values to visualise the differences among levels of `fyear` (2009, 2010, 2011, and 2012). To start plotting differences among years I wrote:

```
NewData      <- expand.grid(year = levels(fyear), protection = 0)
X            <- model.matrix(~ year + protection, data = NewData)
NewData$Pred <- X %*% fixef(shalit5)
NewData$SE   <- sqrt(diag(X %*% vcov(shalit5) %*% t(X)))
```

To start plotting differences among protection levels I tried:

```
NewData2      <- expand.grid(protection = levels(littlesha$protection), fyear = 0)
X2            <- model.matrix(~ fyear + protection, data = NewData2)
NewData2$Pred <- X2 %*% fixef(shalit5)
```

But after this line I get this error message:

> Error in X2 %*% fixef(shalit5) : non-conformable arguments

Could someone please shed some light over what I am doing wrong?